# How to transform a string with a list of dicts within just to a list

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I do have  next string:

```
"[
    { 
     "name" : "name_1",
     "codes" : ["some_code_1", "some_code_2"]
     },
     
     {
     "name" : "name_2",
     "codes" : ["some_code_1", "some_code_2"] 
     }
  
]"
```

How can I make this string to be just a list type ?

Comment: [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: It also looks like JSON, so `json.loads()`

Answer (score 0):

You could evaluate using the builtin `eval` wich i *DO NOT RECOMMEND*, or the "safe version" by ast wich is [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), but these two each have problems. The builtin `eval()` has security issues and the "safe" version is very rigorous in order to prevent malicious code.

I would suggest the [`JSON library`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), which provides a set of tools to encode and decode with json.

Just do this:

```
>> import json
>> to_decode = """
[
 { 
  "name" : "name_1",
  "codes" : ["some_code_1", "some_code_2"]
 },
 
 {
  "name" : "name_2",
  "codes" : ["some_code_1", "some_code_2"] 
 }
]"""
>>> #to decode it here is the solution...
>>> json.JSONDecoder().decode(to_decode)
[
{ 
 "name" : "name_1",
 "codes" : ["some_code_1", "some_code_2"]
 },
 
 {
 "name" : "name_2",
 "codes" : ["some_code_1", "some_code_2"] 
 }
]
```

Or you could use the `loads()` function instead:

```
>>> json.loads(to_decode)
```

Comment: `json.loads(to_decode)`

Comment: thanks, i'll add it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `json` library:

```
import json

sampleString = """
[
    { 
        "name" : "name_1",
        "codes" : ["some_code_1", "some_code_2"]
    }, 

    {
        "name" : "name_2",
        "codes" : ["some_code_1", "some_code_2"] 
    }

]
"""

processedList = json.loads(sampleString)

print(processedList)
```